# Are there any rules of rewriting a linear system to an augmented matrix?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, gaussian-elimination

[image]

If I want to solve the system above, I first have to rewrite it like below. However, are there any particular rules that for instance says, that x has to come first, then y and then z, or can you decide the order by yourself and still make it work?

[image]

The reason I am asking this question, is because I almost always see that people use the same order, where x comes first, then y and then z.

It might seem like a dumb question, but I don't see anyone talking about this anywhere.

**EDIT:** If you can freely rewrite the matrix as you want, would there then be a way to rewrite it, that would make it easier to solve the system?

Comment: It doesn't matter as long as you memorize which is which (or you were asked to provide them in a particular order). People typically prefer lexicographical ordering, since it's easier to remember.

Comment: @Florian 
What about if I didn't care about the lexicographical ordering, but instead I am trying to put it into such an order so that it would make it easier for me to solve? Would it for instance be easier for me to solve the system if I made the x's come first because it's the only variable in this system that contains two 1's?

Comment: Usually, when one wants to make the system easier to solve, one resorts to techniques more powerful than merely reordering it, which is not very useful by itself. Do you know about Gaussian elimination (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination), the reduced row echelon form (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form), etc.?

Comment: @user164324: Sometimes you may need to switch elements, e.g., when applying pivoting (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivot_element#Examples_of_systems_that_require_pivoting). In general, it won't make things easier if you permute them though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write your system of equations as a matrix and then solve, what you are implicitly doing is to consider the matrix form of the system, which is

$$A\cdot\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=b,$$
where $A$ is the matrix of coefficients of the variables and $b$ is the column vector of independent terms.

In the system above, the first column of $A$ contains the coefficients which multiply with $x$, the second column contains the coefficients which multiply with $y$, and the third column goes analogously with $z$. This just happens due to the definition of the matrix product.

You can always change the order of the variables if you wish so, but you must do the same change to the columns of the matrix, so that the final equations, after computing the matrix product, are the same. For example, if you swap $x$ and $y$ then you must swap the first and second columns.

Analogously, you can change the rows of the matrix if you wish, but then you'll have to change the components of the $b$ vector in the same way, in order for the system to keep being the same as before.